# Ist "der Preis des Ripples" gutes Deutsch?

Tags: genitive

When speaking about the price of something, I thought you always use genetiv.

But I saw some articles where it says "Der Ripple Preis".

Which one is correct? Or maybe I can use both.

If somebody doesn't know, Ripple is an alternative currency like bitcoin.

Comment: Do you mean _Ripplekurs_ (rate of the Ripple)? For me, it does not make sense that a currency itself has a price. If so, both _der Ripplekurs_ and _der Kurs des Ripples_ are possible. Notice that _Kurs_ is a noun and must be capitalized.

Comment: *Preis* is a substantive and therefore should start with an uppercase letter (except in compounds as *Milchpreis*). For currencies *Preis* is somewhat unusual and *Kurs* is typically used.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Mit einer Google-Suche findet man tatsächlich Webseiten auf denen von "Ripple Preis" (sic!) gesprochen wird, im weiteren Verlauf wird dann zu "Ripple Kurs" (sic) variiert. Aber warum machst du nicht eine Antwort aus deinem Kommentar?

Comment: @IQV Jemand war schneller.

Comment: Note, that *Ripple* might be misunderstood as a dialectal variant of (Schweine-)Rippchen in some regions.

Answer (score 12):

As Ripple is a (modern) kind of currency, the same rules should apply as for ordinary currencies, say dollar or birr.

A good expression in German is

> Der Dollarkurs ist gesunken.

You also could say

> Der Kurs des Dollars ist gesunken.

which would be grammatically correct, but it sounds a bit awkward because it is unnecessarily complicated. When speaking of dollar, the usual way to say this is just the one above (*Dollarkurs*). However, for other, less common currencies, phrases such as

> Der Kurs des Birr tendiert positiv.

would be more usual (as opposed to *der Birr-Kurs*). It just depends on the currency and the speech habits that have developed regarding that specific currency.

#### Some additional hints

1. Note that "Kurs" is a word used for currencies where "Preis" would be used for other goods and services.

   > Der Butterpreis ist schon wieder gestiegen.
   >
   > Der Preis landwirtschaftlicher Produkte sinkt zum Schaden der Bauern dauern.

   You do not say

   > *Der Kurs der Butter ist gestiegen.

   although you theoretically (when insisting on logic rather than habits) could.
2. Note also that "Preis" can be used in a different way, referring not to money but to other things "paid" (or given away, or lost) when getting something else.

   > Der Preis des Lügens ist der Verlust der Glaubwürdigkeit.

   Meaning: if you lie all the times, people will stop believing you. You "pay" for lying with a loss of credibility. However, you cannot<sup>1</sup> say

   > *Der Kurs des Lügens…
3. Note, thirdly, that in the two-word expressions cited in your question and in some comments, in German you obligatorily have to use a hyphen:

   - Der Ripple-Kurs [not: Ripple Kurs]
   - Der Ripple-Preis [not: Ripple Preis]

   Writing such word combinations without a hyphen (or any other special character but a blank) is standard in English, and therefore many people with first language German have started to thoughtlessly imitate this manner, but still it makes a bad impression of your ability to express yourself adequately in written German.

---

<sup>1</sup> You "cannot" in a sense of: in ordinary situations of communication. Of course, technically and physically you can, and with some creativity you also could find situations where you "can" say this in a meaningful way, e.g. in a humouristic text or in poetry.

Comment: Thanks for that! I just want to make sure, will you ask "wessen preis" oder "welcher preis" to get the answer "der preis der Tomato" z.b.

Comment: Good sentences are: "Der Tomatenpreis auf dem Wochenmarkt ist stabil geblieben". - "Was kosten Tomaten heute?" You can also make up a situation where "Wessen Preis?" is an acceptable expression, but this would happen rather in a German language classroom, not in everyday life. E.g. imagine a textbook dialogue: A: "Der Tomatenpreis ist gestiegen." - B: "Wessen Preis?" - A: "Der Preis von Tomaten!" But in everyday oral communication you would rather ask "Der Preis von was?" (e.g. when the communication takes place at a loud location).

Comment: The term "Kurs" can be applied for everything sold via stock market. Currencies, shares, gold and even agricultural products like corn or butter. Therefore when talking about the stock market one could say "Der Kurs der Butter ist gestiegen". Allthough it's very uncommon in everyday language.

Comment: I'd have said "Der Kurs des Dollar**s**", and this doesn't sound awkward to me at all.

Comment: @Cubic  I agree for the *s* in *Dollars* the missing of which was a typo. As for awkwardness: I am speaking of everyday oral communication. In more formal contexts (e.g. in academic writing) "der Kurs des Dollars" may be acceptable or even standard.

Comment: @mtwde   "Der Kurs der Butter und der Kurs von Schweinhälften" - yes, in the specific context of stock market. The answer, however, focuses on use of language in everyday situations, i.e. situations a learner of German at that level would typically be facing.

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann: In addition to this I'd like to mention that everyday German tends to avoid constructions like 'der Preis der Butter'. You would rather say 'der Butterpreis (ist / die Butterpreise sind wieder gestiegen)' or '(die) Butter ist wieder teurer geworden.' For 'der Kurs des Dollars' it may be different as long as it is not spoken German. In a police report you may read 'die Tür der Wohnung wurde aufgebrochen', but when talking to a fried you will always say 'bei mir wurde die Wohnungstür aufgebrochen.'

Comment: Would it be correct to ask "Welcher Kurs ist gestiegen?" or the right question would be "Wessen Kurs ist gestiegen? Or both work?

Comment: @RalfJoerres   "Butterpreis" rather than "der Preis der Butter": indeed! That was my very argument. Wasn't it? I wrote "possible, but unnecessarily complicated".

Comment: @Tomas.  Both (*Welcher Kurs ist gestiegen*  and *Wessen Kurs ist gestiegen*) seem acceptable. The Welcher-Phrase is best in "normal" (everyday) language. *Wessen* sounds very high-pitched for everyday usage. *Wessen* can also be irritating because normally it refers to people, not things or concepts. But technically, yes, it should be possible to say or write this, given an appropriate (highly formal) situation or context.

Comment: Are there more examples like this when instead of saying "Der x des y" the words are connected together like in Dollarkurs, tomatenpreis. I mean words like Kurs and Preis which tend to stick with other word.

Comment: And another question. Can I answer the question "Welcher Kurs gestiegen?" with genetive "Des Dollars"? The question asks for Nominativ and the answer is in genetive which sounds to me a bit off

Comment: @Tomas: It's a general German construction. For example: "Die Transportkosten (Kosten des Transports) übersteigen den Warenwert (Wert der Ware). Der Schiffskapitän (Kapitän des Schiffs) nimmt eine Kursänderung (Änderunge des Kurses) vor. Der Regierungschef (Chef der Regierung) lehnt den Gesetzesentwurf (Entwurf des Gesetzes) der Bundestagsfraktion (Fraktion des Bundestages) ab. Die Gesetzesnovelle (Novelle des Gesetzes) zum Werbeverbot (Verbot der Werbung) stößt beim Oppositionsführer (Führer der Opposition) auf Ablehnung."

Comment: I just notice a type in my previous comment that I had missed: "Änderunge" should be just "Änderung"

Comment: @Celtschk thanks for that great answer! Can you help with my other question:                                                        " Can I answer the question "Welcher Kurs gestiegen?" with genetive "Des Dollars"? The question asks for Nominativ and the answer is in genetive which sounds to me a bit off"

Comment: @Tomas: You would ask: "Welcher Kurs *ist* gestiegen?" The verb "ist" cannot be omitted here. And the answer would then be "Der des Dollars". "Der" refers back to the "Kurs" in the question (i.e. it's short for "Der Kurs") and is nominative. And then the genitive "des Dollars" refers to that. Of course you could also explicitly answer "Der Dollarkurs".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77252/discussion-between-tomas-and-celtschk).

Answer (score 1):

Proper German allows three ways to form the expression of "price for something", although, if you are talking of some sort of currency, "Kurs" would be the more appropriate term. I'll be using this here:

- > Der Kurs des Ripple <sup>1</sup>
- > Der momentane Ripplekurs <sup>2</sup>
- > Der aktuelle Ripple-Kurs <sup>3</sup>

As you see,

> <s>Der Ripple Kurs</s>

is none of them. So you can actually use the genitive to form such an expression, form a compound substantive, or couple the compound substantive using a hyphen.

---

1. Genitive used to make the connection
2. §37 *Rechtschreibregeln*, on *Zusammenschreibung*: *E3: Dieser Regel folgen auch lexikalisierte, ursprünglich aus dem Englischen stammende bzw. aus englischen Einheiten gebildete Zusammensetzungen: Bandleader, Cheerleader, Chewinggum, Mountainbike, Bluejeans, Hardware, Swimmingpool.* Whether this one applies here, is questionable. "lexikalisiert" is no attribute I would see with "Ripplekurs".
3. §45 *Rechtschreibregeln*, in *Schreibungen mit Bindestrich*: *E1: Aus anderen Sprachen stammende Verbindungen aus Substantiv + Substantiv, die sich im Deutschen grammatisch wie Zusammensetzungen verhalten, werden zusammengeschrieben; ebenso ist die verdeutlichende Schreibung mit Bindestrich möglich: Sexappeal (Sex-Appeal), Sciencefiction (Science-Fiction), Shoppingcenter (Shopping-Center), Desktoppublishing (Desktop-Publishing), Midlifecrisis (Midlife-Crisis)*

Comment: What about "Der Ripplekurs" isn't that the 4th way?

Comment: Read again, especially second item.

Comment: I read again, I would say it's the 4th way

Comment: The second item above **says** "der momentane Ripplekurs". Why would you want that twice?